# Espresso how to test if Activity is finished?

Tags: android, testing, android-activity, android-espresso, android-testing

I want to assert that my Acitivty that I am currently testing is finished when certain actions are performed. Unfortunately so far I am only to assert it by adding some sleep at the end of the test. Is there a better way ?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.LargeTest;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class MyActivityTest {

    Context context;

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MyActivity> activityRule
            = new ActivityTestRule(MyActivity.class, true, false);

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        super.setup();
        // ...
    }

    @Test
    public void finishAfterSomethingIsPerformed() throws Exception {

        activityRule.launchActivity(MyActivity.createIntent(context));

        doSomeTesting();

        activityRule.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                fireEventThatResultsInTheActivityToFinishItself();
            }
        });

        Thread.sleep(2000); // this is needed :(

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            assertTrue(activityRule.getActivity().isDestroyed());
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 61):

In my case I can test for `isFinishing()`:

`assertTrue(activityTestRule.getActivity().isFinishing());`

instead of:

```
    Thread.sleep(2000); // this is needed :(

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        assertTrue(activityRule.getActivity().isDestroyed());
    }
```

Another advantage of `isFinishing()` is, that you do not need the Version check.

Comment: Sure thing, using `isFinishing()` is nice, but you're not addressing the main point of the question which is how to work around the sleep.

Comment: In my understanding the OP was asking for a better way to assert, so he can avoid the `Thread.sleep`.

Comment: I noticed that you can avoid the `Thread.sleep()` after testing your code. However you forgot to mention that so I edited your answer to make the point more explicit.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe a little late but this is also possible:

```
assertThat(activityRule.getActivityResult(), hasResultCode(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED));
```

Answer (score 6):

**ActivityTestRule** is deprecated now. So, my answer is based on **ActivityScenario** which is the new alternative for ActivityTestRule.

To test whether the current activity is finished(destroyed) or not. You can simply code like -

**Way.1**
ActivityScenario.launch(YourActivityName::class.java).use { activityScenario ->
//Your test code

```
  assertTrue(activityScenario.state == Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED)
}
```

- activityScenario.state tells the current state of the activity under test
- Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED tells that the activity is destroyed

**Way.2**

```
ActivityScenario<MyActivity> scenario = ActivityScenario.launch(MyActivity.class);
   // Let's say MyActivity has a button that finishes itself.
   onView(withId(R.id.finish_button)).perform(click());
   assertThat(scenario.getResult().getResultCode()).isEqualTo(Activity.RESULT_OK);
```

Comment: Way.2 works but you need to correct the way you launch the activity using: `ActivityScenario.launchActivityForResult(MyActivity.class);` instead

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't set a result in your activity, you can just use:

```
assertTrue(activityRule.scenario.result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if its a good practice but this worked for me:

```
assertTrue(mTestRule.getActivity() == null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56491860/9402979, you can use

```
Espresso.pressBackUnconditionally()
assertTrue(activityRule.activity.isDestroyed)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use StartActivityForResult sample below, more descriptions in links.

How to start Activity from FirstActivity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

That's how to finish your SecondActivity to go back to first (without sending result):

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
finish();
```

How to Raise Event when SecondActivity is finished (is wrote in FirstActivity):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

   if (requestCode == 1) {

   }
}//onActivityResult
```

More you can find here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html and there [How to manage `startActivityForResult` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android) there's also how you can send the data you want to get from SecondActivity.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I guess I was not clear enough. My problem is that I don't have a second activity or a first activity. I only have one Activity. So I can use your solution only if I start a dummy first Activity just to be able to start my Activtiy that I want to test from there..

Comment: so you have your runnable and wants to do something after it finished?

Comment: I want to make sure that my activity is closed after the     fireEventThatResultsInTheActivityToFinishItself(); is called

Answer (score 0):

```
val latch = CountDownLatch(1)
activityScenarioRule.scenario.onActivity {
        it.lifecycle.addObserver(object : DefaultLifecycleObserver {
            override fun onDestroy(owner: LifecycleOwner) = latch.countDown()
        })
    }
latch.await(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS).let { Assert.assertTrue(it) }
```